# Improving the speed of insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to optimize the following query in SQL Server 2008. The execution plan shows that this query is 90 percent relative to the batch. The insert shows 75 percent. I am looking at an option to do batch insert, concurrent insert etc. Could somebody throw light on speeding up the process. Could I do `SqlBulkCopy` or use the `OpenRowset` function? I have ensured that there are indexes for all the fields in the where condition

```
INSERT INTO [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[xxxxxxx] WITH (Tablock)
    SELECT 
        s.companyId,
        ti.tickerSymbol,
        s.securityName, 
        ex.exchangeName,
        cur.currencyName, 
        primaryFlag = CASE 
                         WHEN ti.primaryFlag = 1 AND s.primaryFlag = 1  
                            THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                      END,
        ti.tradingItemId,
        peq.pricingDate, peq.priceOpen,
        peq.priceHigh, peq.priceLow, peq.priceMid,
        peq.priceClose, peq.priceBid, peq.priceAsk,
        peq.volume, peq.adjustmentFactor, peq.VWAP,
        mc.marketCap, mc.TEV, mc.sharesOutstanding
    FROM
        ciqsecurity s 
    INNER JOIN
        CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.MarketDataTemp1 a ON a.companyId = s.companyId 
    INNER JOIN
        ciqtradingitem ti ON s.securityid = ti.securityid
    LEFT JOIN
        ciqpriceequity peq ON peq.tradingitemid = ti.tradingitemid
    LEFT JOIN 
        CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.MarketDataTemp2 mc ON (mc.companyId= s.companyId AND mc.pricingDate = peq.pricingDate)
    INNER JOIN
        ciqExchange ex ON ex.exchangeId = ti. exchangeId
    INNER JOIN
        ciqCurrency cur ON cur.currencyid = ti.currencyId
    ORDER BY
        peq.pricingDate DESC
```

I have tried to slice the insert into batches but it seems to take longer. For e.g the following

```
DECLARE @BatchSize int = 1000

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [xxxxxx].[dbo].[xxxxxxx]  with (Tablock)
select 
    s.companyId,
    ti.tickerSymbol,
    s.securityName, 
    ex.exchangeName,
    cur.currencyName, 
    primaryFlag = case when ti.primaryFlag = 1 and s.primaryFlag = 1 then 1 else 0 end,
    ti.tradingItemId,
    peq.pricingDate,
    peq.priceOpen,
    peq.priceHigh,
    peq.priceLow,
    peq.priceMid,
    peq.priceClose, 
    peq.priceBid,
    peq.priceAsk,
    peq.volume,
    peq.adjustmentFactor,
    peq.VWAP,
    mc.marketCap,
    mc.TEV, 
    mc.sharesOutstanding
from ciqsecurity s 
    inner join CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.MarketDataTemp1 a on a.companyId = s.companyId 
    inner join ciqtradingitem ti on s.securityid = ti.securityid
    left join ciqpriceequity peq on peq.tradingitemid = ti.tradingitemid
    left join CoreReferenceStaging.dbo.MarketDataTemp2 mc on (mc.companyId= s.companyId and mc.pricingDate = peq.pricingDate)
    inner join ciqExchange ex on ex.exchangeId = ti. exchangeId
    inner join ciqCurrency cur on cur.currencyid = ti.currencyId
order by peq.pricingDate desc

IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize BREAK END
```

Result with set statistics on

```
Table 'ciqExchange'. Scan count 17, logical reads 67, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ciqCurrency'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MarketDataTemp1'. Scan count 10, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ciqSecurity'. Scan count 500, logical reads 53703, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ciqTradingItem'. Scan count 17, logical reads 33082, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 11382, logical reads 1193682, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ciqPriceEquity'. Scan count 15681, logical reads 96425, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 3, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'MarketDataTemp2'. Scan count 17, logical reads 1648, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Execution Plan 1

[image]

Execution Plan 2

[image]

Comment: Indexes will slow down an insert. Do you need all the indexes you have created?

Comment: So wait... is the INSERT part slow, or the select?  Speding up an insert is challenging .  Speding up the select to get all records to insert in memory...whe's the bottle neck. and is the indexes on the select not on the target table?  disabling logging/recovering... it's all the overhead of a transactional system that can make the inserts slow.

Comment: is the order by needed for the insert ?

Comment: The easiest solution solution can be this if the destination table has indexes you can drop the indexes before proceding to the insert of the records. Then you can recreate the indexes

Comment: And I have also a question: how long it takes the SELECT query execution?
And how long it takes the entire INSERT command?
There are some big time gap between the two queries or not?
Avoid to use the solution of a custom batch sizes... It is never a good Idea

Comment: And also: there is no need to use order command in the select query. Order command will make use of tempdb to sort the records... For sure will impact the performance

Comment: If that is the code for your batch inserts I would agree that would take longer because you have coded yourself an infinite loop. There is no condition so it will just keep inserting the same rows over and over and over....

Comment: There are absolutely no indexes on the destination table

Comment: Whats the problem with the condition Sean ?

Comment: The select by itself is taking 11 secs . But the insert into select is taking only 2 sec

Comment: Can you run the query with this command before "SET STATISTICS IO ON" and paste the result please ?

Comment: The select is taking so long because it has to "download and render" the data, thats the difference between insert and select statement

Comment: Anyway... 2 sec or 11 sec is not so long to wait... How many records it manage ?

Comment: I am testing only small set of data . I need to ultimately run 40 to 50 million rows

Comment: Hi Darion, I have added the stats

Comment: I see lot of Scan Count... 
Scan counts should be as low as possible. As for Logical Reads, you want them to be as high as possible and more than physical reads is preferred (read from cache as opposed to drive).

Comment: Are you sure the Indexes are properly present on the tables in the select command?
If yes, try to update statistics on indexes... It will help a lot

Comment: But why are you ordering though?

Comment: Do  I need to update statistics every time  I run ?

Comment: No Tom, Just one time for statistics... But I'm pretty sure the query is not using indexes... Can you check if the fields in the join has indexes ?
Usually when we have more that 1 Scan count is because of missing indexes... Focus on these tables: ciqPriceEquity, Worktable, they have lot of scans !

Comment: I just checked  ciqpriceequity has clustered index on tradingitemid

Comment: Didnt understand from where Worktable comes from as it is not in my query

Comment: May be that Worktable comes from the "order by"...
Did you run the command with the sort final command ?

Comment: regarding worktables: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: No I had commented the order by and run the query. I think it  coming with set staticstics on

Comment: Actually is tricly to find where the problem is from there...
Can you include execution plan image of the select command in the question ? It will help a lot... But I'm pretty sure the problem comes from missing or unused indexes...

Comment: I have updated the post with the execution plan. I was finding it a challenge to fit every thing. Just took screenshot of what mattered. rest was showing 0 percent cost

Comment: is there some TABLE SCAN ? if yes on wich tables ?

Comment: There are table scans on 2 tables MarketDataTemp2 Cost 1%
MarketDataTemp2 Cost 0%

Comment: I'm back Tom, well, actually I think that you don't have so much action margin to speed up the query...
The query seems to be well tuned and that doesn't have critical point to rework... It simply extract more than 40-50 million records and takes only 11 sec to execute... For me you can't improve more the query... 
You can make some checks on index fragmentation and in case rebuilt them but you will not go under the 5 seconds...
In my opinion the query its ok and there are not bottlenecks...

Comment: Thanks Darion I felt the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query seems to be well tuned and is seems that it doesn't has critical points to rework.
It simply extracts more than 40-50 million records and takes only 11 sec to execute. In my opinion me you can't improve more the query... 
You can make some checks on index fragmentation and in case rebuilt them but you will not go under the 5 seconds... I think the query its ok and there are not bottlenecks...